Google Chrome & Edge Crashing When Loading Browser Settings
I am using the updated versions of both browsers. When attempting to enter browser settings, especially Chrome's, the browser crashes. This has become prevalent when attempting to login to LinkedIn and a select few other apps. I'll reach the login page, Chrome will attempt to automatically log me in, and browser will crash. I've attempted to uninstall and reinstall, and update the browser.

If you delete the user profile. Does the crashing issue resolve itself?

Ramhound, I’ll attempt it. It does not happen on my PC, only on my HP Laptop.
